# JPA spec on merge without cascade annotation

Tags: jpa, merge

JPA spec on Merging entity:

```
Case 1:
For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the cascade element value
cascade=MERGE or cascade=ALL, Y is merged recursively as Y'. For all such Y referenced
by X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note that if X is managed then X is the same object as
X'.)

Case 2:
If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where cascade=MERGE
or cascade=ALL is not specified, then navigation of the same association from X' yields a
reference to a managed object Y' with the same persistent identity as Y.


X  ----> X'
|        |
|        |
Y -----> Y'
```

Does this mean that MERGE cascade annotation is optional? What is the difference between these two cases?

Answer (score 0):

No , it means that -in case 2- it will refer to the old Y entity inside the persistence context, though it might be changed in memory to Y' but the change is not reflected to the persistence context since cascade.MERGE is not set

EDIT : First lets confirm the terminology , X and Y are the entities before merge in the Persistence context, X' and Y' are the entities after merge in the Persistence context ... here he says that in case of cascade.MERGE, Y' will be a new version different than the old Y, it will be overridden by the new merged entity state (thus the state of Y in the persistence context changes) .... but without the cascade.MERGE , Y will not be merged, so the new Y entity in the persistence context (i.e. Y' ) is the same as the old (I mean its state will not be changed after the merge ... I am talking about the version in the persistence context) .... the changes done to Y will not be reflected in the persistence context ... Y (in the persistence context) will remain the same , thus Y' = Y ( state of Y in the persistence context will not change after the merge)

Comment: If Y is not merged to Y',  the X' will still reference to the old Y. If there is another entity Y' already in the persistence context, the X' will reference to the Y'. Is my understanding correct? thanks.

Comment: Thanks. To make sure I understand it correctly, for example, Employee references to Department (without cascade). Now a detached instance Employee emp1 is assigned to a detached Department dept1  (emp1.department=dept1) and then make some changes to dept1. do merge(emp1).  If the merged emp1' references dept1, and dept1 becomes managed, the changes to the dept1 will be saved to database on commit/flush. If this is the case,  there is no difference between case1 and case2. My initial understanding is that the dept1 will not become managed, and its changes will not be synchronized to database.

Comment: your initial understanding is correct,dept1 will not become managed , but consider a case when there's already a managed object called dept and a managed object called emp (before the merge), now after merge, emp will change to emp1, but dept will not be changed to dept1 (i.e. if you changed the dept name it will not get merged, the old dept name will be the same), thus the new emp1 is pointing to the old dept,this is case 2, It think the point that you are missing is that you are not considering that emp and dept were already managed before the merge.4 more info,check Pro JPA 2 , p.148 to 150

Comment: thanks. I understood what you described here. But the case 2 says differently which confuses me: [ then navigation of the same association from X' yields a reference to a managed object Y' ].   emp1 is merged to existing emp. emp.getDepartment() is pointing to the detached dept1.  But the case 2 says, it should point to a managed Y' (that is managed).

Comment: yes i admit it is confusing, but what  I understand is that Y' is the managed version of Y after the merge operation, be it the one to which the changes where applied or the previous one , so the following sentence clarifies it when it says that it will have the same persistence identity as Y ... so it's the previous existing managed entity not the newly modified... if you check Pro JPA 2 the pages I mentioned you will find a very clear example

Comment: I searched the book. Do I need to buy it to read the pages? Spec should have more examples. thanks.

Comment: After merge, will emp.getDepartment() return dept1 (detached, changed) or the dept(pre-existing managed)?  what if there is no pre-existing dept in the persistence context? thanks.

Comment: I think no legal free copy is there ... emp.getDepartment() return dept after merge() because it's now pointing to the pre-existing managed ... if there is no pre-existing dept .... If it doesn't exist because it was removed , an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown ... if does't exist because it has never been there, it depends on the provider, either throw an IllegalArgumentException immediately or allow the reference but throw  IllegalArgumentException  at flush time ... welcome any time

Comment: Thanks. if the detached department is not merged, and the persistence context does not have the department with the same identifier, but it does exist in database. In my opinion, it should not throw any exception since it is normal. It is just a reference to an entity in database.

Comment: Yes ... It will load it from the DB first to the persistence context then the new employee merged will point to it

Comment: I am reading your answer: "Y will not be merged, so the new Y entity in the persistence context (i.e. Y' ) is the same as the old .... the changes done to Y will not be reflected in the persistence context ... Y will remain the same , thus Y' = Y", still confused. Actually Y is detached and changed, Y' != Y. If you can make it more clear, I would like to accept it as answer :)

Comment: kindly check the edit and consider that X and Y are the entities before merge in the Persistence context, X' and Y' are the entities after merge in the Persistence context